# Object keep passing through floor in a scene in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, ios11, arkit

I am trying to make an easy ball toss game using ARKit for iOS 11 and I have a scene that keep three nodes (lights, floor which it's physics body type is et to static, trash can or sth to keep the tossed balls in it)

After plane detection and placing the trash can on the ARPlane there is a method called every time when user tap a button to toss a ball. The ball's physics body type is dynamic and is being created and tossed in the view controller file (not created in the .scn file) using SCNNode and applying forces using physicsBody.

```
let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 0.025)
let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)
let forceDirection = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2)
let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ball, options: nil))
physicsBody.isAffectedByGravity = true
physicsBody.allowsResting = true
physicsBody.mass = 1
physicsBody.restitution = 1
physicsBody.friction = 0
physicsBody.applyForce(forceDirection, asImpulse: true)
ballNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
```

nodes in .scn file
[image]

physics body attributes of the floor in scene:
[image]

**Everything is fine with tossing the balls using the forces and adding them to the scene using sceneView but the PROBLEM is that the balls are keep passing through the trash can and the floor itself even though they're kinematic and/or static.**

**UPDATE: After setting the collisionbitmask for both ball and plane (floor) now the problem is the balls are not going to stay inside the trash can even though I've reduced the restitution of the trash **

Comment: Set the collision bit mask to the ball and the floor.

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: did you find a solution for that? If so can you please publish it?